# Flatten nested XML including body text

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to transform some XHTML fragments into a particular XML form for subsequent processing. I would like to achieve this with XSLT.

I have seen some questions and answers here on flattening nested XML structures, but nothing obvious that included multiple element body text nodes, so...

The example input XHTML is as follows (this example is the simplest case, in theory I can have any level of nesting of spans with different class attributes):

```
<div>
    <span class="one">
        Leading One Text
        <span class="two">Two Text</span>
        Trailing One Text
    </span>
</div>
```

I am trying to generate this output XML:

```
<document>
    <text class="one">Leading One Text </text>
    <text class="two">Two Text</text>
    <text class="one"> Trailing One Text</text>
</document>
```

Can this be achieved with XSLT, and if so, how?

Comment: Note that I made a small but significant [change](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18608245/revisions) to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="div">
  <document>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//text()[normalize-space() != '']" />
  </document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="div//text()">
  <text class="{../@class}">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
  </text>
</xsl:template>
```